# I need to combine 632 mp3 files

Tags: macos, command-line, audio, mp3, midi

I have 33h:38m:06s of music that I am trying to combine (for a project) into one large `.midi` file. So far, I have 632 .MP3 files in one folder, and I am trying to combine them into one file.

**What is the best approach to achieving this?** Obviously, cloud-based merging software is out of the question since I have too much data to merge. Is there a way to accomplish this through a terminal (I'm on mac) command?

Comment: into a `.midi` file? As in a file for keyboard synthesizers? How do you expect to do this from mp3 *audio* files?

Comment: Install `ffmpeg` (like with `brew`) and then you can merge files, you will find tips here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate